Prisma Error after uploading in Namecheap Shared-Hosting
I uploaded my web-applciation developed with NextJS in Namecheap shared hosting. Here i used the Node.Js App setup to uplaod. I followed all step correctly.
But While I run it shows this following error.

I tried the follwoing configurations in the script of the package.json file
#1
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "node server.js",
  "lint": "next lint",
  "generate": "prisma generate"
}

#2
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "prisma generate && next build",
  "start": "node server.js",
  "lint": "next lint"
}

#3
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "prisma generate",
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "node server.js",
  "lint": "next lint"
}

What should I do to run the app and connect database?

Can you look at the Namecheap logs to confirm if npm install occurred, and that the prisma generate command ran right after it? The script you have for #3 should work as long as you are running npm install on Namecheap

Firstly, your scripts should look like this, if the postinstall is inserted, i observed my modules stop getting installed
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "node server.js",
  "lint": "next lint"
}

Secondly, you will need to use putty to run this command i also observed you will keep running out of memory if you decide to use the terminal, just go through the configuration and installation process for putty, bear in mind the Host Name or (IP address) on putty is unique but your port will be 21098 for shared hosting as well
Putty Image here 
You might encounter another error when the command is successfull,
error PrismaClientInitializationError: Prisma Client could not locate the Query Engine for runtime "debian-openssl-1.0.x".

This happened because Prisma Client was generated for "debian-openssl-1.1.x", but the actual deployment required "debian-openssl-1.0.x".
Add "debian-openssl-1.0.x" to `binaryTargets` in the "schema.prisma" file and run `prisma generate` after saving it:

generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "debian-openssl-1.0.x"]
}

Don't panic, just insert the binaryTargets and run npx prisma generate again on putty.
All should be fine if this steps are taken.
